# How to hide amazon SES recipients email addresses

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-ses

In Amazon SES is there a way hide email recipients without sending one sendEmail to every email? like send them in bulk but only show the recipient email

```
const ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" });


    const params = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: emails 
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Html: {
                // HTML Format of the email
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: content
            },
        },
        Subject: {
            Charset: "UTF-8",
            Data: title
        }
    },
    Source: `someName <${process.env.DEFUALT_SES_MAIL}>`
    };

    const sendSesEmail = ses.sendEmail(params)
```

Comment: You can use the BCC field to send to the recipients.  Though some spam checkers will look for this and block.  Is there a reason you dont want to send one at a time? Cost?

Comment: Don't want to recipient to see all emails receiving this email just for user experience

Comment: What I meant was that you could send to one email at a time instead of bulk. Bulk is limited to 50 per mail anyways so you'll have to send in batches.